# Apache Camel route with MongoDB gives an error No bean could be found in the registry

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, apache-camel

I am trying into implement a route to insert content into MongoDB. Below is the route I tried and it gives me an error:

**Caused by: org.apache.camel.NoSuchBeanException: No bean could be found in the registry for: localhost:27017 of type: com.mongodb.client.MongoClient**

```
from("rabbitmq:localhost:5672/tasks?autoDelete=false&routingKey=camel&queue=task_queue")
        .bean(itemDetails, "consumeItemDetails(${exchange})")
        .to("mongodb://localhost:27017?database=ItemDB&collection=ItemDetails&operation=save");
```

I was not sure where and how to define a bean of type MongoClient and how I can pass the host and port numbers as parameters. Could anyone please guide me on this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare a `MongoClient` bean. If you're running your application through Spring Boot (starter), it will provide your app with a bean named `mongo`. Otherwise, you need to follow Chanfir's advice.

Answer (score 0):

In your route definition , you need to add the beanId as following :

```
 from("rabbitmq:localhost:5672/tasks?autoDelete=false&routingKey=camel&queue=task_queue")
        .bean(itemDetails, "consumeItemDetails(${exchange})")
        .to("mongodb:mongoBean?database=ItemDB&collection=ItemDetails&operation=save");
```

And  define a bean of type MongoClient with beanId mentionned in your xml/annotation configuration then define database connection params inside the bean :

Example using Spring xml configuration :

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

  <mongo:mongo-client id="mongoBean" host="${mongo.url}" port="${mongo.port}" credentials="${mongo.user}:${mongo.pass}@${mongo.dbname}">
    <mongo:client-options write-concern="NORMAL" />
  </mongo:mongo-client>
</beans>
```

Example using Annotations :

```
@Configuration
public class MongoConfig extends AbstractMongoClientConfiguration {
 
    @Override
    protected String getDatabaseName() {
        return "test";
    }
 
    @Override
    public MongoClient mongoClient() {
        ConnectionString connectionString = new ConnectionString("mongodb://localhost:27017/test");
        MongoClientSettings mongoClientSettings = MongoClientSettings.builder()
            .applyConnectionString(connectionString)
            .build();
        
        return MongoClients.create(mongoClientSettings);
    }
 
    @Override
    public Collection getMappingBasePackages() {
        return Collections.singleton("com.baeldung");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To be able to execute the code using Spring Boot 2.7.3 and Camel 3.18.2, I have to explicitely register the Mongo client when loading the route:

```
 @Autowired
    MongoConfig mongoConfig;
```

then :

```
context.getRegistry().bind("connectionBean", mongoConfig.mongoClient());
```

Is there a way to automatically register the Mongo Client?

Answer (score -2):

you can easily add a bean inside your Application class if you are developing using Java DSL, like this:

```
@Bean("myconnection")
public MongoClient mongo() {
    return new MongoClient("localhost", 27107);
}
```